# Artifactory Deploy Error: HTTP Status 500 - more than one filter accepted this request

Tags: php, artifactory

NOTE: This is a Q&A added to share information

This error comes up when you try to push to a local php repository on artifactory

```
The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

java.lang.RuntimeException: more than one filter accepted this request
    org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.authentication.ArtifactoryAuthenticationFilterChain.acceptFilter(ArtifactoryAuthenticationFilterChain.java:115)
    org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilterInternal(AccessFilter.java:187)
    org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:165)
    org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:67)
    org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:164)
    org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
    org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:62)
    org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryFilter.doFilter(ArtifactoryFilter.java:116)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the issue was that I was using both the generated token and a header specifying the token in the request.

Example:

```
curl -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api: <token>" http://<user_id>:<token>@docker.for.mac.localhost/artifactory/php-local/
```

The fix was to remove the custom header. i.e use only

```
curl http://<user_id>:<token>@docker.for.mac.localhost/artifactory/php-local/
```

Comment: If possible, please add a note suggesting how the answer can be improved when you down vote it.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same error with an otherwise working Artifactory OSS 5.2.1 with the very same stacktrace while browsing the webapp with Firefox.

Also log entries such as this appeared in artifactory.log:

```
2021-02-24 23:11:18,340 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] [ERROR] (o.a.w.s.a.ArtifactoryAuthenticationFilterChain:107) - 2nd matching filter ArtifactoryBasicAuthenticationFilter
```

But it looks like it's a client-side / browser thing: when opening the same URL in private mode or in another browser, everything works OK. Restarting the browser fixed the glitch.

(BTW the error appeared using Firefox 74.0.1)